# Cannot SSH into Pi4 from Windows

Tags: ssh

I know this question has been asked one million times - but all the input I found so far didn't help.

Long story short: I cannot SSH into my Raspi anymore.

Yesterday I've installed Raspberry Pi OS x64 as a clean installation from scratch (no upgrade installation). I spent all the day installing and configuring several things, e. g.:

- Docker
- ufw
- fail2ban
- nginx

I cannot count how many times I SSHed yesterday into my Raspi after installation - maybe three dozen times, without any issues.

This morning I wanted to continue my work, but `ssh myRaspiUser@myRaspi` gives `Permission denied, please try again.`. `myRaspi` has `sudo` rights.
The same happens for `ssh pi@myRaspi`. Both accounts are set up for `password` authentication.

There is another user `raspiUserWithoutPassword` which uses `publickey` authentication - and this one can still connect.

My client is a Windows 10 machine with all the latest updates. In all cases, I'm using the same windows account `MyWindowsUser` for connecting with `pi`, `myRaspiUser` or `raspiUserWithoutPassword`.

When connecting the Raspi via HDMI cable to my screen and log in via UI, I can still access all accounts without any issues.

Here are some things I already tried:

- `ping myRaspi`

```
Pinging myRaspi.fritz.box [192.168.178.20] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.178.21: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.21: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.21: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.21: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.178.21:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 65ms, Average = 18ms
```

- `ssh -v myRaspiUser@myRaspi`

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to myRaspi [192.168.178.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to myRaspi:22 as 'myRaspiUser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:9Q0YBbDhnTvnJ/Jt4IEdTN29L6dFcdfR5iRjl9L8Qqk
debug1: Host 'myRaspi' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mX01zgqbmFoeRnLdwc04tX4ekPg0s/yH6Skh8aT+Mlw
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mX01zgqbmFoeRnLdwc04tX4ekPg0s/yH6Skh8aT+Mlw
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\MyWindowsUser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
myRaspiUser@myRaspi's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

- `ls -la /dev/tty`

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Jun  6 12:21 /dev/tty
```

- `sudo ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

- Using IP address instead of host name → same errors
- Using `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` → same errors
- Calling `ssh pi@127.0.0.1` when locally logged in as `myRaspiUser` (Raspi is attached via HDMI cable) → same errors
- Simplified password (`HelloWorld123`) to avoid any typos → same errors
- `grep PasswordAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
```

- `ls -ld /run` (as user `myRaspi`, no `root`/`sudo`)

```
drwr-xr-x 31 root root 920 Jun 6 18:23 /run
```

- `ls -ld /var/run` (as user `myRaspi`, no `root`/`sudo`)

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 4 Apr 4 16:25 /var/run -> /run
```

- `cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf` (as user `myRaspi`, no `root`/`sudo`)

```
cat: /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf: No such file or directory
```

After several attempts, I'm receiving `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.178.21 port 22: Connection timed out`. I assume this is due to fail2ban and I can retry after a couple of minutes.

The question is pretty simple ^^ how can I SSH into my Raspi again using password authentication?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `grep PasswordAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config` say?

Comment: I've updated my question with the output - seems like only comments

Comment: Remove the `#` before `PasswordAuthentication yes` and try again. Restart `sshd` after you've edited the file.

Comment: Still fails with the same error

Comment: You said that you can log-in from the console. Can you (from the console as root) stop `sshd` ; run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` in the foreground ; next try to login from your Windows and see if that produces any usefull information?

Comment: I launched `sudo -i` and then `/usr/sbin/sshd -d`. This prints three private host keys and `Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd`

Comment: Next step in debugging: `ls -ld /run` , `ls -ld /var/run` and `cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf`

Comment: I've updated the question with the results (last three bullets). Please note that now `publickey` authentication for `raspiUserWithoutPassword` fails as well :(

Comment: Put the debugging steps in an answer and added a new step to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the user to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like this:

```
AllowUsers myRaspiUser
```

But I have no clue why I have to do this on my own and why this was not necessary before

Comment: AllowUsers specifies a list of local accounts that may accept SSH connections. The list is definitive: any account not listed cannot receive SSH connections. Although this might now work, this is not the solution.   What is  the uid of your `myRaspiUser`?

Comment: Executing `id` returns `uid=1001(myRaspiUser) gid=1001(myRaspiUser) groups=1001(myRaspiUser),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),104(input),108(netdev),995(docker),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)`

Answer (score 1):

We're more or less debugging in the comments. Someone else who comes across this question won't want to go through all the comments, so these are the steps we took.

1. Is password authentication allowed for `ssh`? Normally, it should be. That is why the line

```
# PasswordAuthentication yes
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is commented out. If the line is set to `no`, this would be a reason why login with password would not work.

2. To see what is going on, we launched the `sshd` on the host in the foreground with the debug option. Do this as root (or sudo'ed). This can produce usefull information.

```
sudo sshd -d
```

3. Normally, the directory `/run/sshd` is created automatically. The creation should be specified in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf`, which should contain

```
d /run/sshd 0755 root root
```

Manually creating `/run/sshd` with the owner and permissions above may result in a working password login on `sshd`. However, that will be gone after a reboot. So, for a test, create `/run/sshd` manually, for permanence, create the `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf`.

4. Sshd now complains about not having host keys. Which is odd as it worked before. The host-keys should be available in `/etc/ssh/`; a simple `ls` should confirm whether they are there. If they are, `sshd` should be able to find them.

For good measure, you can delete them and re-create them:

```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Beware that all clients will give you a message that hostkeys have changed and that you might be victim of a man-in-the-middle attack. You're not; you did this yourself. Updating the `known_hosts` on the clients will solve this error message.

Comment: Thank you! I will try in my lunch break. And what should be the content of the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf`? Empty? Or the same as `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: `d /run/sshd 0755 root root`

Comment: Still not working, now `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` returns three statements `debug1: Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/<<file>>` and `sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting`

Comment: don't know what you did with ssh on your Pi, but you probably shouldn't do that again ;-). Next step added to the answer.

Comment: I checked and `/etc/ssh` already contained six files `ssh_host_*`. When opening e. g. `nano /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`, the file is empty. But when running `sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`, I see the RSA private key. The same after recreating the files and I still cannot login. Are some privileges missing? Thank you for your patience with me! It's so frustrating... I double-checked literally every single command which I executed on Sunday - not a single one is related to `ssh` - I have absolutely no clue what happened from Sunday to Monday

Comment: When you ran the `sshd -d` and it said that it could not access the keys, did you run it sudo-ed or as root?

Comment: Neither of the two - I executed all commands under my `myRaspiUser` account which has `sudo` privileges. But I prefixed none of the commands with `sudo`

Comment: That explains why `sshd` cannot find the keys. Do `sudo sshd -d`, otherwise it will not get executed as root.

Comment: When running `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d`, it now returns three private host keys and ends with `Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd`. Then I executed `sudo nano /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf` with the file content from your reply. Now `sudo sshd -d` still gives the same error, but when starting the service and executing `sudo service sshd status`, I see the output `pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<my client's IP address> user=myRaspiUser` - but my password is correct, because I can manually login via UI and has only letters

Comment: I have it, see the other answer!!! Ey man, thank you so so so much!!! Do you have anything like a _Buy Me a Coffee_ account? I really want to say thank you for your support